# Why does this prototypjs observe have a bind on the callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I ran into this pattern in a project.

```
$('some_form').observe('keypress', (function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
        this.some_function()
        event.stop();
    }
}).bind(this));
```

I want to know why there is `.bind(this)` on the handler. This is all in the initialize function for a Class.create() if that helps.
I am also asking this with the intent to convert this to jQuery.

Comment: if you ask me, it already is jQuery (with `observe` plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the binding, the scope (`this`) would be the `some_form` element. Since `some_function` isn't a member of the form element, you wouldn't be able to call it.

With the binding, the scope is the containing scope, which has access to `some_function`.

Here is another pattern that solves issues with scope, which is compatible with even super ancient browsers.

```
var _this = this;
$('some_form').observe('keypress', (function(event) {
    _this.some_function();
}));
```

Comment: *"Without the binding, the scope (`this`) would be"* `this` isn't scope.

Comment: It's a *reference* to the current scope!

Comment: No, it isn't, not remotely. `this` and scope have nothing to do with each other. Scope is about what variables and such are in scope (accessible). `this` is a special function argument. You can have the same `this` across lots of scopes, and the same scope with lots of different `this` values (as, in fact, is the case with jQuery event handlers). Some people refer to `this` as the "context," but even that's misleading (as the specification refers to execution contexts, which are different). It's just the current `this` value.